# npm init error: Invalid name: "donn&jul"

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

My `npm` version is `2.5.1` and my `node` version is `0.12.0`. When I try to run `npm init`, I get the following error:

> npm ERR! Invalid name: "donn&jul"

Here is the screenshot: [image: npm init error screenshot].

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> From the [official NPM reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#name):
>
> > The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line, and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe characters.

I believe `&` is not url-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today and tried a lot of solutions but discovered that the problem was the project's primary folder name was the cause of the problem

here is my project's main folder before: Product Color Picker [Custom Widget]
[ERR! Invalid name: "product-color-picker-[custom-widget]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXBZv.png)

here is after I changed the folder name and removed the brackets and the error is gone: Product Color Picker [Custom Widget]

[Npm working fine with no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqWf8.png)

BTW, keep in mind that if you were in VSCode you will need to re-open the folder after changing its name from the system as it will appear broken with no files [because the original folder name you opened  changes]